# How can i set maxLength of textbox according to radio button list in JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a radio button list in ASP.Net, and a textbox underneath that. I want to be able to change the maxLength of the textbox according to whats selected in the radio button list. I have tried everything, but im missing something obviously.

Here is my JS:-

```
function ValidateCCN() {
    var x = document.getElementById('RadioButtonListPayment');
    var y = document.getElementById('TextBoxCCN');

    if (x.selectedIndex = "Visa")
        { y.maxLength = '5'; }
    else
        { y.maxLength = '2';}
}
```

Here is my HTML/ASP

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelCard" CssClass="labels" runat="server" Text="Select a payment option: "></asp:Label><br />
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListPayment" runat="server" onchange="ValidateCCN();">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Visa">Visa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MasterCard">MasterCard</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Discover">Discover</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="American Express">American Express</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:Label ID="LabelCCN" CssClass="labels" runat="server" Text="Credit Card Number: "></asp:Label><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCCN" CssClass="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Error:-
     *"the else statement doesnt work"*

Comment: What isn't working with your current solution?

Comment: do you have `<%=RadioButtonListPayment.ClientID%>` in a JS file? If so, that is your problem... That piece is ASP.net code

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems.  You are going to have specifically set the GroupName in your ListItems and then loop through those in javascript to selected one.

ASPX:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListPayment" runat="server" onchange="ValidateCCN();">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Visa" GroupName="CCType">Visa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MasterCard" GroupName="CCType">MasterCard</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Discover" GroupName="CCType">Discover</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="American Express" GroupName="CCType">American Express</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

JS

```
function ValidateCCN() {
    var y = document.getElementById('TextBoxCCN');
    var x = document.getElementsByName('CCType');
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (x[i].checked) {


        if (x.value == "Visa") 
          y.maxLength = '5';
        else
          y.maxLength = '2';
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

Also you should be using the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=` in your if-statement.

Comment: i have tried x.value already and just did it again with your suggestions, the if-statement skips the first condition even though it is being satisfied

Comment: Radio buttons must be found on the page by name not id.  Example code updated above

Answer (score 0):

You are using a assignment operator in your `if` statement instead of a comparison operator.  Change this:

```
if (x.selectedIndex = "Visa")
```

to this

```
if (x.selectedIndex == "Visa")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**js**

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="theName"]').change(function(){
        if($('#option-1').prop('checked')){
            alert('Option 1 is checked!');
            $('#name').attr('maxlength', '13');
        }else{
            alert('Option 2 is unchecked!');
            $('#name').attr('maxlength', '5');
        }
    });
});
</script>



**html**
 <body>
<input type="radio" name="theName" value="1" id="option-1">no
<input type="radio" name="theName" value="2">yes
<br>
<label>name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name"></input>

</body>
```